# Get person who share calendar with me EWS Managed API (C#)

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, office365

Hello is there any possible way to get people who share calendars with me (FolderId or atleast persons email) without knowing email account. I want to make dynamic appointment get depend on shared calendars in programatically way. Using (c#)

Comment: Is this a calendar that you have shared with others, or a calendar that is shared with you and others from another mailbox?

Comment: Calendars are shared by others for me from another mailboxes.

Comment: Are you trying to get the email address of the person that shared this calendar with you? The more details you can give me about your scenario the better chance I have of answering your question.

Comment: See this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766747/ews-access-all-shared-calendars