# Creating appointments on other calendars, shared with me, using EWS API

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I hope this is the right forum to ask this question.
My requirement is as mentioned below:
-> I need to create an appointment on my Default calendar and the same on other calendars that are shared with me (or created by me and shared with others) by using Exchange Services (EWS).
-> By shared, i mean all those calendars that I can see under my 'Other Calendars' group in Office 365.
-> Now, I have reffered many links which help to create appointments on my mailbox, default Calendar. This part works fine(Link : (http://technico.qnownow.com/how-to-create-appointment-using-ews-exchange-web-services/)
-> Then I moved on to access shared calendars so that I can create the same appointment on them.
Used this : [EWS - Access All Shared Calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766747/ews-access-all-shared-calendars)
-> However I do not get the PidTagWlinkAddressBookEID property in any of the items fetched.

The code works fine till I get the fiResults collection.
I get names of all the calendars under Other Calendars section in this collection.
The problem is when I iterate over this collection (as you can see in the code) , i am trying to get the **PidTagWlinkAddressBookEID property value in each item and its not present in the item.**
And this is the reason I am not able to retrieve the FolderID at the end.
But i tried number of ways to do it since i get the collection of items and I can see my shared calendars' names in those items.

Since i created the shared calendars, I tried to use my mailbox address at the end in this part of the code :

FolderId SharedCalendarId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, ncCol[0].Mailbox.Address);

However the calendar retrieved in this case is the default calendar with displayName as Calendar.

Since each item in the itemcollection ( fiResults collection) represents the corresponding shared calendar
Please let me know if we can use any property in the Item class to create an appointment.

I tried one more approach to create appointments on shared calendars:

First i tried to access all the calendar folders by using:

```
private void ViewCalendarFolders(string mailBox)
    {
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_Folder_Path = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(26293, MapiPropertyType.String);
        PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        psPropSet.Add(PR_Folder_Path);
        FolderId rfRootFolderid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, mailBox);
        FolderView fvFolderView = new FolderView(1000);
        fvFolderView.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
        fvFolderView.PropertySet = psPropSet;
        SearchFilter sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.FolderClass, "IPF.Appointment");
        FindFoldersResults ffoldres = exchangeService.FindFolders(rfRootFolderid, sfSearchFilter, fvFolderView);

        var res = ffoldres.Where(f => f is CalendarFolder).ToList();
        if (res.Any())
        {
            foreach (Folder fld in res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fld.DisplayName);

            }
        }
    }
```

Then I tried to create appointments on the CalendarFolders fetched.
I succeeded in creating appointments on two calendars:
1) My default calendar
2) The calendar which I have created and shared with others.

the piece of code shown above fetches all the calendar folders except those which are created by other users and shared with me. (Even though I can see them under the Other Calendars section in office 365 and can even create appointments on them through UI i.e. manually)

Kindly let me know how to create appointments on such calendars which are shared by others with me.

Note: I have Editor rights on these type of calendars

Thanks

Comment: One more thing which I found is, the item collection retrieved using  (EWS - Access All Shared Calendars) as mentioned in my post is a collection of Email Messages i.e the invitations which I have got for the Shared Calendars. So is it possible to retrieve the calendar folder on the basis of this invitation...Damn..I am confused...Please help

Comment: Can anyone please answer this?