# Office365 + EWS: Get a list of shared mailboxes in an account

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Let's say I have an O365 account `user@example.com` with a few shared mailboxes in it, e.g. `shared1@example.com`, `shared2@example.com`.

Is there any way to get a list of these two shared mailboxes without knowing their specific name?

ie. I'm looking for a function that works as such:

```
list = ews.GetListOfSharedMailboxes("user@example.com")
println(list) --> outputs Array("shared1@example.com", "shared2@example.com")
```

If not possible in EWS, is there any other API that supports this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean and how the Mailboxes have been added. eg if somebody has just added Mailboxes to their outlook profile because that configuration is held within the Outlook profile on the client then no you can't.

For shared Contacts and Calendar folders that the user has added (which means that are also available in OWA) then you can use the Shortcuts like [EWS - Access All Shared Calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766747/ews-access-all-shared-calendars) or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/bbff797d-21df-4bf9-8796-e7b81d818f93/cews-retrieve-all-shared-contacts-available-from-user?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

The last place to check is AutoDiscover Additional Mailboxes are return in the results it would suggest you test that with the ewseditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/

Cheers
Glen