# how can I get shared calendars with ews-java-api

Tags: java, calendar, exchangewebservices, shared

```
￼FindItemsResults<Item> fiResults = fFolders.getFolders().get(0).findItems(cntSearch, iv);

for (Item item : fiResults.getItems()) {
    try {
        Object wLinkAddressBookEID = null;
        item.tryGetProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition,(OutParam<Object>)wLinkAddressBookEID);
        byte[] ssStoreID = (byte[]) wLinkAddressBookEID;
```

Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.definition.ExtendedPropertyDefinition
>   cannot be cast to
>   microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.definition.PropertyDefinition
>     at
>   microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.ServiceObject.tryGetProperty(ServiceObject.java:455)
>     at
>   microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.ServiceObject.tryGetProperty(ServiceObject.java:441)

Comment: I highly support this question as I've been trying to get the solution laterly with C# or Java (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920641/ews-access-shared-calendars-items-appointments).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I've found this question. But when I try to use item.tryGetProperty, the code of ServiceObject ,try to cast PropertyDefinitionBase to PropertyDefinition, here throws java.lang.ClassCastException. Do you know why?

Comment: I could find the shared calendar folderId in MFCMAPI thanks to Glen Scales, but cannot do it programmatically (preference in Java). I don't know how to access ExtendeProperties (we need PidTagWlinkEntryId and then, decode it to get ewsId AFAIK). I get the same cast exception as you. Not very helpful, sorry.

Comment: Thanks any way.
I've create issues :https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues/575.

Comment: Can you mail your successed code to me?
email:caojian.1224@gmail.com
Thanks...