# Get Outlook Task NavigationGroups via EWS

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

**What I want?**

I need to retrieve the list of all the NavigationGroups (called as 'Folder groups' by outlook users) belongs to outlook tasks (highlighted in attached picture).

**What I did so far:**

I found several examples which has implemented with COM objects. In my case, I need to do the same with EWS. Unfortunately I could not find any clue from either MSDN or any related forums. So, I doubt that EWS does not support this feature.

Am I correct? If not please enlighten me

[image]

Comment: Those Navigation Groups are an outlook feature and are saved locally. EWS only communicates with the exchange server, which does not know of the users Navigations Groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support for these in EWS but you can access them using EWS. These are stored as Navigational shortcuts which are documented in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee179467(v=exchg.80).aspx and stored in the Common Views under the Non_IPM_SubTree of the mailbox. eg here's one example of getting the Calendar shortcuts [EWS - Access All Shared Calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766747/ews-access-all-shared-calendars)