# Accessing "Other Calendars" in exchangelib

Tags: python, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook.com

I'm currently using exchangelib to connect to the Office365 EWS.  My current scenario is that I want to access the calendars for our meeting rooms.  Their calendars show up when I click the "Add Room" option from within Outlook.  They also appear when I add them to the "Other Calendars" section of my Calendar view.

When I attempt to use the meeting room's e-mail address as the account, then check the Calendar, I get the following error:

```
exchangelib.errors.ErrorFolderNotFound: No useable default Calendar folders
```

So I figured that I would just access the calendar via my login, instead; as though I'm viewing the Other Calendars section in Outlook.  The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to access these calendars.  I can access my own with no issue.

When I looked at the C# implementation for EWS, there is a way to search for folders and that's where you'll find the Other Calendars.  I don't see anything like this in exchangelib.

To give an example:

```
credentials = Credentials(username='My email address', password='My password')
config = Configuration(credentials=credentials, server='outlook.office365.com', has_ssl=True)
email = # My e-mail address (I also attempted with the room's e-mail address)

account = Account(primary_smtp_address=email, credentials=credentials,
                  autodiscover=False, config=config)

for f in account.folders:
    print f
```

Result:

```
<class 'exchangelib.folders.Calendar'>
<class 'exchangelib.folders.Contacts'>
<class 'exchangelib.folders.Tasks'>
<class 'exchangelib.folders.Messages'>
<class 'exchangelib.folders.Folder'>
```

The 'Calendar' option cannot iterate, but the 'Folder' option can.

```
for f in account.folders[Folder]:
    print f
```

Result:

```
Folder (Conversation Action Settings)
Folder (Conversation History)
Folder (Files)
Folder (Journal)
Folder (Notes)
Folder (Quick Step Settings)
Folder (RSS Feeds)
Folder (Social Activity Notifications)
Folder (Yammer Root)
```

None of these options seem to give me what I'm looking for.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I have found the magic of `account.root.get_folders()`.  I can now see a very large list of folders.  However, I still don't see one that appears to be usable for Other Calendars.

I've been reading about solutions that others are using in C# and came across this thread:

[EWS - Access All Shared Calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766747/ews-access-all-shared-calendars)

It appears that they have some sort of search filter, but I'm unable to locate it within the `exchangelib` libraries.

Then I found another thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2bfe798e-501f-421e-9a9a-76ae7eaf57c8/other-calendars-in-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

This one spoke about how the Other Calendars is a folder under the Calendars object.  However, when I query `account.calendar.get_folders()` I come back with 0 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `No useable default Calendar folders` error means that exchangelib couldn't find the default calendar folder among the folders for the account. There could be a number of reasons for that. You may still be able to find a calendar folder in `Account.folders`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the other calendar forlder by query account.calendar.children:

```
for cal_folder in account.calendar.children:
    if -1 !=str(cal_folder).find('my_Calendar'):
        myCalendar=cal_folder
        break

for item in myCalendar.all():
    print(item.subject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit of context in case this helps someone else, we ran into this in situations where User A has access to User B's inbox, but does not have access to User B's calendar. If User A is added to User B's calendar sharing, the problem is resolved.