# how to get share calendar list in exchange 2007

Tags: calendar, exchangewebservices

I am using glen's code([EWS - Access All Shared Calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766747/ews-access-all-shared-calendars)) to get share calendars, it work fine on exhange 2010/2013/office365. but get error on exchange 2007.the code has error like this:

```
        psPropset.Add(PidTagWlinkAddressBookEID);
        ItemView iv = new ItemView(1000);
        iv.PropertySet = psPropset;
        iv.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Associated;
```

the ItemTraversal.Associated only support on exchange 2010, not support exchange 2007.
can anyone help me? very thanks.

Comment: You will need to use another API such as WebDAV or MAPI

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.  i am not familiar with WebDAV or MAPI. Can i call these api with java? If it is possible, can you give some examples.  Now i have another question,In your code (SearchFilter sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Common Views");) Are there multiple language problems on  wording "Common Views" ?

Comment: On Common Views no because it a Non_IPM_Subtree folder so it's not visible to user, Shortcut and group names (eg "Other Calendars") would be affected by language but I've never tested on non English mailboxes. Webdav on Exchange was End of Life in 2007 (2007 is EOL in October this year so anybody running this version should be on the upgrade path especially in the light of recent events).  Maybe try https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnetinterop/2008/07/21/connecting-java-to-exchange-over-webdav-with-apache-httpclient/ but I would avoid 2007 if you can as its a lot of hassle IRL .

Comment: thank you so mach, glen.

Comment: Hi glen, i need your help. my question is:   FolderId confRoomFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(email)); I want to know all the email ? is there any way? thank advance.

Comment: On 2007 ? no you could stick all the addresses you want in a Distribution list and then expand that list everytime you want those address. Otherwise look at using LDAP to query Active Directory directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Not only 2007, also includes 2010,2013,2016